# comparing text of a button to a label in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, string

I have the following code:

```
    int index = [self.colorlist count];
    int random1 = (arc4random() % index);
    NSString *color1 = [self.colorlist objectAtIndex:random1];
    [Button1 setTitle:color1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I want to compare the Button 1 text to a different label with .isEqualTo but using
        if button1.text isEqualToString: label 
does not work. What is the proper syntax for calling button 1's text, rather than button1.text. Thanks!

Comment: Please save bandwidth and everyone else's time by consulting the documentation. UIButton and UILabel are not difficult class docs to read. The answer is perfectly obvious at a glance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not bothering to look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
button.currentTitle
```

And

```
button.titleLabel.text
```

The first is a read-only reference to the current text on the button.

The latter is a readwrite reference to the text property of the label on the button.  The label reference however (`button.titleLabel`) is itself readonly.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it by following code

```
if([button.currentTitle isEqualToString(textField.text)])
{
    //Succes part
}
else
{
    //Failure Part
}
```

Hope this answer may help you